# Align python figure text variables

Tags: python, matplotlib, text

How can we ascribe a fixed space to the `plt.text`?

The wanted display is

```
a =   1
a =  10  
a = 100
```

A failed example is

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y = 0.3
for k in [1,10,100,1000,10000]:
  y+= 0.1
  g = 2.2*k
  plt.text(0.3,y,'k='+format(k, "<7d")+'g='+format(g, "<7.1f"))

plt.savefig('variable_tring.png',format='png')
plt.show()
```

The output is ugly:

```
a = 1 b = 2.1
a = 100 b = 2.2
a = 1000 b = 2.3
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is to use [horizontalalignment](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/text_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text.set_horizontalalignment) option in plt.txt.
I'm sure there will be more elegant method than this. This is a sample script.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y = 0.3
for k in [1,10,100,1000,10000]:
    y+= 0.1
    g = 2.2*k
    plt.text(0.3,y,'k=')
    plt.text(0.45,y, format(k, "7d"),horizontalalignment='right')
    plt.text(0.5,y,'g=')
    plt.text(0.7,y,format(g, "7.1f"),horizontalalignment='right') ## Try tweaking the first argument to avoid overlap

plt.savefig('variable_tring.png',format='png')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Strictly following your demand:
Set y = 0.8 and use y-=1

```
y = 0.8
    for k in [1,10,100,1000,10000]:
        y-= 0.1
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way is to set the font as `momospace`

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
font = {"fontname": "DejaVu Sans Mono"} # ubuntu
#font = {"fontname": "Consolas"} # windows

y = 0.3
for k in [1,10,100,1000,10000]:
  y+= 0.1
  g = 2.2*k
  plt.text(0.3,y,'k='+format(k, "<7d")+'g='+format(g, "<7.1f"), **font)

plt.savefig('variable_tring.png',format='png')
plt.show()
```

[Result figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0mRJ.png)